# Как сделать модальное окно processing во время обработки запроса сервером?

Tags: веб-программирование, java-ee, primefaces, dialog

Пока обрабатывается запрос сервером, хотелось бы вывести клиенту модальное окно, которое закрыло бы ему возможность продолжать кликать на кнопочки.

Как вообще такие механизмы реализуются, на чем они базируются? Как понять продолжительность отображения окна? Объясните, кто делал, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С использованием primefaces все реализуется просто:

> https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/status.xhtml